# Dynamic Reference to Sheets: VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and need some help with a macro I'm trying to program

I have 31 sheets representing days of the month and a "Master" tab with the current date (this is used for data input). I want the person doing the data entry to be able to sign and date the sheet, click a button and copy paste the values of the initials into the appropriate date tab. I have mined and manipulated data using the INDEX/MATCH functions with an embedded INDIRECT reference, but I don't know how to do this in VBA.

Example, I'm doing data entry for Aug 14th. The master tab with retrieve all of August 14th's data. After inputting, I want to click a button on a userform and it will copy and paste that into the appropriate "day" tab... in this case, the tab named "14"

Thanks for any help! I'm learning, but getting there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to refer to the sheet name as a format of the date. For example:

```
Function TheSheet(ByVal dt As Date) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(Format(dt, "dd"))
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set TheSheet = ws
End Function
```